# Creating file from python results

Tags: python

How to create a python file from given results, I need to save it in a text document or in excel. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use the `csv` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 2):

Whether the quiz code is right or not, whether it can be optimized or not, here's a little help on your error. Since Python says that in

```
text_file.write(score)
```

there must be a string argument, not an int, just typecast your score variable into a string as in

```
text_file.write(str(score))
```

and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says everything, your `score` variable holds an int, but it needs to be a string to be written to a file. (It even tells you the line number.)
So convert it to a string, like this: `text_file.write(str(score))`

Apart from that, you have a bug in your code caused by a typo in a variable name:
`socre = score + 0`. This does not cause the error, but will cause the code not to work as expected. This is a perfect example of why lazyness can be terrible when programming: By copy-pasting your code block, you copied the bug as well, and now you have multiple bugs by copying a redundant code. Using a function instead and calling it multiple times would have kept the bug in a single place.

Also you are importing the same module `random` multiple times, which hurts readability of your code a lot. Put all imports on the top of your module, and do not write the same import multiple times (once it is imported it stays imported).

Answer (score 0):

I think that this page could be a good starting point for you: http://www.python-excel.org/

It points to a number of different modules that should be able to do what you're asking for. (As long as I understood your question properly ;) )

// Mike